# How to import github code to your android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I found a scrollable sortable table view code on github 
https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView
but I am not sure how to put it in my current android studio project.

It says

*To use the this library in your project simply add the following dependency to your build.gradle file.*

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:0.9.5'
    }
```

Repository Content

tableview - contains the android library sources and resources

app - contains an example application showing how to use the SortableTableView

It's clear that I should copy the tableview folder and add the dependencies on build.gradle. Where should I copy the tableview folder to? Or how does dependencies look for the code?

https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView

Comment: do not copy anything, simply add the compile directive in your gradle file

Comment: add the dependency, and under Features, it shows you how to use it. you don't need to do anything else. you can also download the demo zip, unzip it and import it in AS to see how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an android library. So you only need to add the dependency. How to use the library in android project is explained in detail in its github page under Features.

Comment: what if it's not an android library? i mean how does putting that line of code make the source code available for me to use?

Comment: @Jack Smother -- if its not a dependency, usually most are, then there should be a (jar) file which you download, and copy and paste into the libs folder of your project and it gets picked up that way.

Comment: @Jack Smother The dependencies will be downloaded from the internet first time and saved to local folder in computer. For eg. if the dependency added is a maven dependency it will be stored in .m2 folder (In linux it will be in home directory). From next time if local dependency is available it will be used directly without searching in online repos.